# Silverstripe Modeladmin: Gridview pagination - change items per page

Tags: gridview, silverstripe, modeladmin

I'm using Silverstripe for the first time and have been doing a lot of research. There is one thing I can't get done, although I found some information about it. I'm using Modeladmin with 3 dataobjects, eg. Customer, Contract, ContractType. For now the pagination is set to 15 items per page. However, I would like to see only 8 items per page for all my dataobjects. Is there a way to do this without having to extend the Page class for all of my dataobjets?

Many thanks.

Comment: You want each tab show 8 items of the related DataObject, or do you want ONE list with 8 items mixed of your three DataObjects?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `default_items_per_page` to 8 using the configuration API or YAML syntax, which will be honoured in all cases where a GridField is created with a GridFieldPaginator component, and doesn't set its own page size.

Note that ModelAdmin is an example which *does* set its own page length (described in [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46614593/2812842)), so you will also need to set that configuration property as well.

There are probably other parts of the code you're using (other SilverStripe modules) that are setting page sizes without letting users configure them, but that should catch most of your cases.

```
# File: mysite/_config/config.yml
ModelAdmin:
  page_length: 8
GridFieldPaginator:
  default_items_per_page: 8
```

or in a _config.php file:

```
Config::inst()->update('ModelAdmin', 'page_length', 8);
Config::inst()->update('GridFieldPaginator', 'default_items_per_page', 8);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your ModelAdmin class, you can set the page length, e.g.:
`private static $page_length = 5`